# strange issue with scales domain

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a really strange issue with scales, if I put the domain of the (in this case) yscale like this 
`.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.ycoord; })])`

It sets up my axis wrong, like it is only show in half.
The strange thing is that, to solve this, I tried for a while and then put a / 1 at the end, like so:

`.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return (d.ycoord / 1); })])`

And it did show the axis correctly, as in these screenshots
[image]

[image]

And also here there's the full code on jsfiddle: 
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/svjFe/)

So my question is: why it behaves like this? I'm really clueless about this and was wondering if anyone was able to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that what you're interpreting as numbers (`ycoord`) are actually strings because they come directly from the CSV. That is, instead of 140 you have "140", which as a string is indeed smaller than "95". So the determined maximum for the scale is incorrect. The D3 functions that actually require numbers (such as the scale function) implicitly convert the strings you give them to numbers, so there's no error message.

To fix this, simply convert your strings to numbers before you do anything else.

```
dataset.forEach(function(d) { d.ycoord = +d.ycoord; });
```

Comment: thanks, i thought that numbers were read as numbers and not as strings, that solved it!